# Powershell: Get-service check running or not running

Tags: powershell, service, sccm

I have the following problem:

When I use:

```
Get-Service -Name CcmExec -ErrorAction silentlycontinue
```

I get the follow list:

```
Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Running  CcmExec            SMS Agent Host
```

or

```
Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Stopped  CcmExec            SMS Agent Host
```

When I use

```
$service = Get-Service -Name CcmExec -ErrorAction silentlycontinue -ComputerName $Computername
write-host "$service"
```

I only see ccmexec but not "running' or stoppend".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want to see from `Write-Host` is the status you could use this:

```
Write-Host $service.Status
```

Or you could do something like this:

```
Write-Host "$($service.Name) is $($service.Status)"
```

There are a couple of problems with the code presented in your comment. First, you're using multiple `if` statements, rather than `if`, `elseif`, and/or `else`. (You could aslso just use a [switch statement](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730937.aspx).) Second, it's actually matching both `Running` and `$null` because you're using `-match` instead of `eq`. Try this instead:

```
if ($ccmservice.Status -eq "Running") {
    $ExcelCell.cells.item($ExcelRow, 11) = "Running"
    } elseif ($ccmservice.Status -eq "Stopped") {
    $ExcelCell.cells.item($ExcelRow, 11) = "Not running"
    } elseif ($ccmservice.Status -eq $null) {
    $ExcelCell.cells.item($ExcelRow, 11) = "Not installed"
    }
```

You can get more details on PowerShell's comparison operators [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759.aspx).

Comment: Its not working but maybe its because I make a mistake. I use this code

   $ccmservice = Get-Service -Name CcmExec -ErrorAction silentlycontinue -ComputerName $computer
   if ($ccmservice.Status -match "Running") {
   $ExcelCell.cells.item($ExcelRow, 11) = "Running"
   }
   if ($ccmservice.Status  -match "Stopped") {
   $ExcelCell.cells.item($ExcelRow, 11) = "Not running" 
   }
   if ($ccmservice.Status  -match ($null)) {
   $ExcelCell.cells.item($ExcelRow, 11) = "Not installed" 
   }

But I get always back "Not installed". I checkt and the service is running.

Comment: Thank you. I writing my first check script. But that was my only problem. Thanks again. Tom